# Get pixel colour from a Webcam

Tags: objective-c, macos

I am trying to get the pixel colour from an image displayed by the webcam. I want to see how the pixel colour is changing with time.

My current solution sucks a LOT of CPU, it works and gives me the correct answer, but I am not 100% sure if I am doing this correctly or I could cut some steps out.

```
- (IBAction)addFrame:(id)sender
{
    // Get the most recent frame
    // This must be done in a @synchronized block because the delegate method that sets the most recent frame is not called on the main thread
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer;

    @synchronized (self) {
        imageBuffer = CVBufferRetain(mCurrentImageBuffer);
    }

    if (imageBuffer) {
        // Create an NSImage and add it to the movie
        // I think I can remove some steps here, but not sure where.
        NSCIImageRep *imageRep = [NSCIImageRep imageRepWithCIImage:[CIImage imageWithCVImageBuffer:imageBuffer]];
        NSSize n = {320,160 };
        //NSImage *image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:[imageRep size]] autorelease];
        NSImage *image = [[[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:n] autorelease];
        [image addRepresentation:imageRep];
        CVBufferRelease(imageBuffer);


        NSBitmapImageRep* raw_img = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[image TIFFRepresentation]];
        NSLog(@"image width is %f", [image size].width);
        NSColor* color = [raw_img colorAtX:1279 y:120];

        float colourValue = [color greenComponent]+ [color redComponent]+ [color blueComponent];
        [graphView setXY:10 andY:200*colourValue/3];

    NSLog(@"%0.3f", colourValue);
```

Any help is appreciated and I am happy to try other ideas. 
Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that this could be made more efficient. Take a look at the `imageFromSampleBuffer:` method in [this Tech Q&A](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2010/qa1702.html), which presents a cleaner way of getting from a `CVImageBufferRef` to an image (the sample uses a `UIImage`, but it's practically identical for an `NSImage`).

You can also pull the pixel values straight out of the `CVImageBufferRef` without any conversion. Once you have the base address of the buffer, you an calculate the offset of any pixel and just read the values from there.

Comment: Thanks phil, I have used that guide a bit and working on trying to get the data out of the buffer.